# ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, parquet

I am working with python in a jupyter notebook.
I am trying to access several parquet files from an aws s3 bucket and convert them all into one json file. I know I have access to the data, but I am getting:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied
```

Here is the code I have:

```
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(name='my-bucket')

all_objects = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket = 'my-bucket', Prefix = 'Files.parquet')
```

I am not sure where the access denied is coming from. Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to give `s3:ListBucket` permission to the IAM user/role.

Comment: Thank you! I called 'for obj in bucket.objects.all():' above in an earlier code chunk, does that not mean I have access to ListBucket?

Answer (score 10):

You can follow this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-and-attach-iam-policy.html), and attach the following policy to the user/role.

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I believe I do have this access, since I am calling 'for obj in bucket.objects.all():' earlier, is there something else it could be?

Comment: Yes. It's the permissions that cause this problem

Answer (score 1):

I did everything in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62940788/2119941) but it didn't work. Regardless you should do it first.

What worked for me is setting up new [key and secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html) for my account in AWS IAM console since I was using one provided from another user account which didn't have access to S3.

I've also set up policy for accessing S3 directly in S3.
Click on `Bucket --> Permissions --> Bucket policy`
and create something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1675850598142",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1675850596389",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::918775241671:user/youraccount@your.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketName"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also you need authenticated session created in boto3 in order to connect, here is my full code:

```
import boto3
import awswrangler as wr

# Define your AWS access key and secret key
aws_access_key_id = "SSSSL22FTPTYGZWDF4"
aws_secret_access_key = "fjsidkljfksjfkjs490340+eVcGaXmcamIOrDDzW"

# Use boto3 to create a session with your AWS credentials
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key
)

# Use awswrangler to connect to your S3 bucket
bucket_name = "mybucket"

# List the contents of your S3 bucket
s3 = session.client("s3")
result = s3.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name)

# Print the contents of the bucket
if "Contents" in result:
    for obj in result["Contents"]:
        print(obj["Key"])
else:
    print("The bucket is empty.")
```

Comment: I am really confused, I gave my user Admin access and it isn't working

Comment: I just realized I wasted two hours cause my bucket in the function was called 'my-bucket' :| :| :| :|

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you need to access your AWS account with a VPN. If you are running the program locally and are not connected to VPN, AWS returns this.